# backlight problem after newest 20.04 update

Tags: updates, suspend

After the most recent software update, my computer screen remains black when I try to come out of suspend state. No response. All I have able to do is reboot. I run Ubuntu 20.04 dual booting with Windows on an HP Pavillion laptop

Does anyone have a suggestion about how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here.... for now, you can check how swap partition size you has assigned to and make some changes there

Comment: you can also test some of those answers listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=20.04+suspend)

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to the reason for the system not waking from sleep? What model of HP are you using? 